# What is the Incoming Stream in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I noticed that Google+ lists "Incoming" under the Streams on the left-hand side of the page.

What exactly is "Incoming" and how is it different than the standard "Home" view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Incoming stream shows content from people who aren't in your circles & they are following you. The Home stream shows content from whom you've explicitly added in your circles